# Reconnecting multiple Ajax.BeginForms when dynamically loading the forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-javascript, ajax.beginform

I have a long form made up of multiple sections, each with its own questions. Each section can be saved independently with an `<input type="submit" value="Save" />` button.

Each section is loaded dynamically into the page (and there are a variable number of sections).

Each form is authored separately as an **Ajax.Begin()** ajax form, but with dynamic loading of the forms it appears UnobstrusiveJavaScript will not bind the submit buttons and they perform a standard postback.

What is the simplest way to reconnect the ajax functionality of the submit buttons?

Comment: See my answer 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183475/dynamically-generated-ajax-beginform/18592603#18592603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the source of UnobstrusiveJavaScript (which is quite small) it leaves permanent event handlers using `.on('submit')` so it should just work with dynamically loaded pages.

Turns out the master form was missing the inclusion of UnobstrusiveJavaScript:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Worth checking fiddler when this sort of thing occurs :)